# AngularJs inject providers error

Tags: angularjs, provider, angular-module, angularjs-provider

I'm trying to inject two providers and I have an error:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module App due to:
>   [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $paginationTemplateProvider

Here's my code:

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['angular-loading-bar', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'])
    .config(function ($paginationTemplateProvider, $cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
        $paginationTemplateProvider.setPath('../lib/angular-utils-pagination/dirpagination.tpl.html');
        $cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = false;
    });
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Would you be able to include the html as well, might make it easier to diagnose the issue

Comment: Because `$paginationTemplate` service isn't defined in the modules you're loading.